# NetSuite saved search combining results to a single line per item

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create a saved search in [NetSuite](http://www.netsuite.com) that shows me the quantity of items available at each location.

The formulas I'm using are

`"CASE WHEN {inventorylocation} = 'Location1' THEN {locationquantityonhand} ELSE 0 END"`, etc. I have entered a formula for each location.

The result it's giving me is:

## Item # | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 | Location 4

### 123456 |    10      |     0      |     0      |     0

### 123456 |     0      |     0      |     5      |     0

### 456789 |     0      |     3      |     0      |     0

### 456789 |     0      |     0      |     0      |     7

Is there any way that I can get the saved search to show this instead?

## Item # | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 | Location 4

### 123456 |   10       |     0      |      5     |     0

### 456789 |    0       |     3      |      0     |     7

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Grouping to achieve this.

In the results tab of your Saved Search, there is a Summary Type field next to each column. Changing 'Item #' to 'GROUP' and the formula fields to "MAXIMUM" should result in the output you want.